# Javascript handler instead of submission with amp-form

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I'm trying to use amp-form and instead of issuing get or post, run javascript function. I also want the validation to work. The only way I was able to do the same was with action="javascript:". It works but with "error" on the console. Is there a better way?

```
<form action="javascript:myFunc();"
      custom-validation-reporting="show-all-on-submit">
```

Comment: @artgb according to https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form "The value must be an `https` URL" and the error is exactly that, albeit it still works.

Comment: @niry you cannot use any Javascript in AMP but you can use `amp-bind` to run Expressions. Can you post code for `myFunc()`? I'll do it with amp-bind if possible.

Comment: @adnanyousafch amp-bind block access to window, document - not what I need. seems like better back off AMP for now - digging into it, the components are *much* heavier than what I need (I prefer accelerated by simplicity, not caching and who knows what) I know that google is really pushing this (it showed up on my search console!) but not there yet.